# Trying to find a syntax highlighter for ColdFusion in Notepad++

Tags: coldfusion, notepad++, railo, cfml

I use CFEclipse for most of my projects and heavy lifting but sometimes I find the need to do a quick fix on pages outside the project scope that is easier to accomplish in a simple text editor.

I have googled but can't seem to find an answer so either a link to a download or a link to how to build my own would be awesome.  thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**: Brien Malone's answer below along with charlie arehart's comments are what people should use at this point as nppColdFusion is no longer maintained as of 23 Sept 2011.

**Disregard**

[nppColdFusion](http://bitbucket.org/bbluemel/nppcoldfusion/wiki/Home) is actively maintained

Comment: This is awesome and exactly wha i was looking for. I like he fact that it is actively maintained.  thanks so much

Comment: I only just discovered how to mark it as the correct answer.  Duh.

Comment: Looks like current maintainer has decided to stop supporting as of yesterday.

Comment: It's a shame 6 years on that there's no good alternative. Just took a look at CFEclipse looks like last release was 3 years ago. While the question is Notepad++ focused, an answer here for another open source alternative would help readers more in this case.

Answer (score 7):

In notepadd ++, go to 'Plugins'> 'Plugin Manager'> 'show plugin manager'. 'Coldfusion Lexer' is listed as available plugin

Comment: Note, the "ColdFusion Lexer" is [nppColdFusion](https://bitbucket.org/bbluemel/nppcoldfusion/wiki/Home)

Answer (score 6):

This question is a few years old now, and unfortunately, the accepted answer involving nppColdFusion is no longer valid because the plug-in doesn't work with NP++ after version 5.x.x and is not being maintained. (It stopped working when Notepad++ switched their plug-in hooking mechanism in version 6.x.x)

The Notepad++ site points to a library of nearly every language highlighter available:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files

ColdFusion (specifically CF9) is listed:
http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_CF9.xml

It's not as good as a full plug-in like nppColdFusion, but it is better than pages of black text.

Comment: And though Brien's comment is itself a few years old now, I would point out that I have had no problem implementing the ColdFusion Lexer (aka nppColdFusion) in later versions of NP++, including the latest as of this writing, 7.5.1. 

And while the original NPP author had stopped updating it, others have continued, the last in 2013. (And FWIW, as for Sublime Text--which many herald as the better "alternative editor" for CFML--it's CFML support shows last being updated in 2012.)

Comment: Updating my prior comment: what I was saying "worked" was the install process via the plugin manager. But I was writing that while using the 32-bit version of NP++ (even if installed on a 64-bit Windows). Sadly, with the newer 64-bit version of NP++, the plugin is not listed in the plugin manager AND manually installing won't work since it's a 32-bit plugin. But if one downloads and installs the 32-bit NP++, that offers to remove the 64-bit one (preserving your NP++ config), then installs the 32-bit one. Then you can add the NP++ plugin manager, find the CF lexer listed, and install it.

Comment: Thanks for keeping it alive @charliearehart

Comment: Unfortunately I found that the NP++ plugin doesn't work with Windows 10. However the CF 9 Lexer works very well.

Answer (score 3):

Just a comment about Tony's answer (Aug 22 '14 at 13:00) : he wrote "*In notepadd ++, go to 'Plugins'> 'Plugin Manager'> 'show plugin manager'.*"

However, in ver. 6.8 (maybe since before), there's no "*Plugins*" menu item on the menu bar. What I had to do is:
**1-** From the **User Defined Language Page**
*http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files*
**Download** the ColdFusion User Defined Language file
*http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_CF9.xml*
Into the Notepad++ Folder

**2-** From the User Defined Language panel, import that file:
*Language* > *Define your language...* then press the *Import button*

*ColdFusion* will then appear at the bottom of the *Language* menu item selection list, and NotePad++ will automatically use it for any .CF file you open.

Comment: FWIW, I see a "Plugins" option in notepad++ 6.8.3.

Comment: Thanks @Delire Web, I can confirm that works, I had to close notepad++ and then reopen it for 'coldFusion' to appear at the bottom of list.

Answer (score 1):

This link might help: http://howardscholz.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/notepad-support-for-coldfusion-8/

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: We must be using a different Google than him.  :-)  First link on my search.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  the nppColdFusion seems like it will meet my needs and I like he fact that it is actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I found that nppColdFusion was working well, until I updated NP++ to version 7.6.6. I have tried just about everything to get it working, but to no avail.

I tried Delire Web's solution and it worked perfectly.

The different formatting (font and background colors) takes a bit of getting used to though.