# What's a good and easy plugin for developing Coldfusion code in Notepad++?

Tags: plugins, coldfusion, notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to find a syntax highlighter for ColdFusion in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194904/trying-to-find-a-syntax-highlighter-for-coldfusion-in-notepad)

Notepad++ is a great tool that allows you to choose the language you're working with. Unfortunately, ColdFusion is not on their list. (I'm currently using xml instead when dealing with coldfusion code.) Are there any plugins that are simple to use and thorough for adding a CF option to Notepad++?

Comment: If you're simply looking for a plugin that adds CFML as a language to Notepad++, you may be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194904/trying-to-find-a-syntax-highlighter-for-coldfusion-in-notepad

Comment: No idea about the downvote, but since you agree this is a duplicate, I'll go on and close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up using:

https://bitbucket.org/bbluemel/nppcoldfusion/downloads

Does exactly what I'm looking for.

**Edit**:

I just looked at the post BoltClock linked to, and it suggests this same plugin. I guess that makes this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free IDE with ColdFusion support, ColdFusion Builder has a free version that is pretty great.